# Clicking a .swf button on a webpage in C# windows forms application webbrowser

Tags: c#, flash, webbrowser-control

I am trying to click on a shockwave flash button in my C# windows forms webbrowser. Currently in my windows forms application, I sign into the website and go the webpage where the button is. I want to then click on my windows form button, and have it click the flash button 5 times with about 15 seconds pause in between clicks. As of now, I have nothing, but a lot of hours of googling and getting nowhere. From what I can tell and have played around with, the mechanics is all wrapped up in the button_2.swf and I have tried to call the javascripts on the website but nothing happens. In the swf, you need to 'rollOver' the flash button and then 'press' to run 'gotoandplay(11)' and at some point there is some xml code running at the end. Yes there is the no flash script in the html code, but it doesnt work properly, so that is out of the question. The html code for the button is as follows:

```
<div id='button'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function disableButton() {
            btn = document.getElementById('luckybutton');
            btn.style.display = 'none';
            btn_clicked = document.getElementById('luckybutton_clicked');
            btn.style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
    <div id='luckybutton' style="z-index:1">
        <script language="javascript">
            AC_FL_RunContent('codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0','width', '373','height', '373','src', '/images/buttons/','quality', 'high','pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','align', 'middle','play', 'false','loop','true','scale','showall','wmode','transparent','devicefont','false','id', '','bgcolor', '#ddeef6','name', '','menu', 'true','allowFullScreen', 'false','allowScriptAccess','sameDomain','movie', '/images/buttons/button_2','salign', ''); //end AC code
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="373" height="373" id="" align="middle" style="z-index:1">
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
                <param name="movie" value="/images/buttons/button_2.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ddeef6" />
                <embed src="/images/buttons/.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ddeef6" width="373" height="373" name="" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
                <!-- no_flash content -->
                    <a href="/button/push_the_button" data-method="post" onmousedown="disableButton();return false;" rel="nofollow"><img alt="Luckybutton" src="/images/slb/luckybutton.jpg?1286570555" /></a>
                <!-- end no_flash content -->
            </object>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    <div id="luckybutton_clicked" style="display:none">
        <img alt="Luckybutton" src="/images/slb/luckybutton.jpg?1286570555" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

way 0: gotoandplay(11) can do with direct way

---

if you have source of flash 
way 1: Pass variable to SWF and in flash check value of variable 
way 2: move mouse and click on button :D use 
[Moving mouse cursor programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647236/moving-mouse-cursor-programmatically)