# How to move cursor in windows form application?

Tags: c#, forms, position, cursor, move

I'm writing an application where I need to move the cursor programmatically. I've tried writing:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(50, 50);
```

But it doesn't work. Im writing an windows form application in c#.

I hope someone can help me :)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want it with button click:

First add InteropServices namespace:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

then create your button click event

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]
public static extern long SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCursorPos(50,50);
}
```

Take a look at this:

[[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647236/moving-mouse-cursor-programmatically][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647236/moving-mouse-cursor-programmatically%5d%5b1%5d)

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't seem to work either :/... but thanks for trying :)

Comment: Did you assign button click to this function? Double click on your button's click event and select button1_Click function or create an event delegate to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

Drag a button on to the form and double click.

then you should get a code behind.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor.Position = new Point(50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

once you click the button the function - **button1_Click** fires and moves your cursor.
Perhaps write here what you want to do exactly, i suspect you will need a loop

ALSO

this might help in your endevours.

```
  Cursor.Position = 
new Point(Form1.MousePosition.X + 50, Form1.MousePosition.Y + 50);
```

Form1.MousePosition is the current position of the mouse on the form.

so the code above would move the mouse 50 units right and 50 units down from its current position.

Also theres a form1_load event, double click the form and use that.

Comment: That doesn't work either. The mouse does not move. All I want to is to move the mouse cursor :)