# Moving mouse cursor in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've wanted to create a program that moves the cursor by pressing the `W`,`A`,`S`,`D` keys. I created a form because it was difficult to put the `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.W)` in the script.

This is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace keyboardMouse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void rdnbtnMove_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.W))
            {
                    Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(      
                        Cursor.Position.Y + 5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it throws this error

> Member 'Cursor.Position' cannot be accessed with an instance
>   reference; qualify it with a type name instead

How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the dup: > simple as replacing "Cursor.Position" with "MousePosition".

Comment: You should also take a look at this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647236/moving-mouse-cursor-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: Your `Cursor.Position = ...` code is working for me, in C#6. And changing to `MousePosition` directly won't work, since it has no setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `Form` your code is on has a `Cursor` property.  That's not what you want to access.

Instead fully qualify the type, as the error indicates:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
```