# C# Move the visible mouse cursor programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I have an issue where I'm trying to automate the movement of the mouse cursor across a webpage in C# using selenium.  Is there some way in C# for me to grab the visible on-screen cursor and move it instead of simulating a mouse cursor that moves across the screen?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647236/moving-mouse-cursor-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move mouse cursor using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

For IE

```
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions {
                        EnablePersistentHover = true
                    };
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

For Chrome

```
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
co.AddAdditionalCapability("enablePersistentHover","true");
driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
```

For FireFox

```
FirefoxOptions _FirefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
_FirefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("enablePersistentHover", "true");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(_FirefoxOptions);
```